# Загрузка файлов на сервер с компьютера

Tags: ckeditor

Как настроить CKEditor таким образом чтоб он позволял загружать файлы на сервер?
 (пока он позволяет вставлять фото (ссылки на фото) со сторонних сайтов). На сайте в примерах нашёл его конфигурацию Article editor где он позволяет загружать изображения на сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, что вам нужно использовать - CKFinder https://cksource.com/ckfinder.
Это файловый менеджер того же разработчика, что и CKEditor. Он позволяет подгружать файлы на сервер с компьютера. О том, как интегрировать в текстовый редактор написано в документации.
Самое важное то, что этот файловый менеджер является платным, но все же позволяет подключать его к редактору без проблем. В большинстве случаев тот функционал, который работает в зарегистрированной версии, не особо и нужен. Незарегистрированная версия файлового менеджера нормально подключается и позволяет выполнять основные функции.